# Error when importing data from a "text" file

Tags: vba, excel

I have more than 100 files that are semicolon delimited files (*.asc, but open the same as a text file) to import into a worksheet.  I'm ok with selecting the file each time and updating the folder in the script as needed. I'm just trying to save time clicking through menus.

I can successfully select the file, but it gives me the "Error 104 Excel cannot find the text file to refresh this external data range" after the .Refresh BackgroundQuery line.

Am I not referencing something correctly?

```
Sub Macro2input()
'
' Macro2input Macro
'
'
    Dim Start1 As Range
    'Dim SourceCells As Range
    'Dim DestinationCells As Range
    'Dim NextStart As Range
    Set Start1 = ActiveCell
    Dim Finfo As String
    Dim vFilename As Variant
    Dim fileToOpen As Variant

    rootDir = "X:\Lab Tests\13-7242\Re-run Calon\1-B"
    Finfo = "All Files (*.*), *.*"

    'Sets the default folder for selecting a file
    ChDrive "X:"
    ChDir rootDir

    Filename = Application.GetOpenFilename(Finfo, 1, "Select A File To Import")
    vFilename = rootDir & Filename

    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "TEXT;" + vFilename, Destination:=Start1)
        .Name = Filename
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 932
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = True
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 8).Select
End Sub
```

Comment: you won't be rather happy with my suggestion but I would do your task with ADODB, not with `QueryTable` which I can't really rely on.

Answer (score 0):

Without now beeing a very good VB wizzard: 
Have you realy checked that in the line with "vFilename = rootDir & Filename" that there is the right Filename in vFilename and you are sure you can find and allowed to access (the exccel-process) the file you have in vFilename? From what I think there is no backslash between rootDir and Filename and so therefore not a valid Filepath.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I've added a \. Same error.  In a previous iteration I directly put the filepath (got the same error), but have since used the variant.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a problem in `Destination:=Start1.`

Please use `Destination:=Range("A" & Lastrow)` instead.